# Preventing registry entry code from requiring admin previliges

Tags: c#, wpf, registry

In my application, I am trying to set my application as startup by adding registry entry using the following code:

```
RegistryKey startupapp = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
startupapp.SetValue("App", "\"" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"" +" -start");
```

But the problem is the registry is added only when I run my application as an administrator. Is there any way I could avoid this this thing, so that my application could add/delete registry entries for the startup app?

Comment: Do you want the application to run on startup for all users, or for the user who is currently logged in?

Comment: @Adam Mihalcin: It would be good to run the application for any user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because HKLM requires admin rights to write to. HKCU doesn't require that.

```
RegistryKey startupapp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

startupapp.SetValue("App", "\"" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"" +" -start");
```

Comment: I have been looking for these words, HKLM requires admin to write while HKCU don't... you saved me man!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to set the application to run on startup for all users, **no**, you cannot get around requiring some kind of administrator access.

Why is this?  Well, as a thought experiment, let's say that Windows allowed applications to set programs to run on startup without requiring an administrator password.  But this would defeat the purpose of a lot of the security improvements in Vista, with the introduction of UAC and the advent of non-administrator accounts by default.  A user could download a game that was actually a Trojan, and the game could set some malware to run on startup for all users, all without requiring the UAC prompt.  Therefore, Windows doesn't allow you to set the program to run on startup without administrator rights.

There are some tricks you can use to get around requiring the user to run your *whole program* as an administrator, though.  My first idea is to have a second program whose sole job is to set the main program to run on startup, and to start it with option `ProcessStartInfo.Verb = "runas"` (assuming that you're using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to start the new process) so that the helper program runs as an administrator, but your overall application can be started without the UAC prompt.

---

**EDIT**: In response to your comment

Yes, if you only care about starting the program on startup for a single user, you have a lot more options.  As [this O'Reilly article](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/startup_0401.html) describes, one option is to write to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run in order to set your program to run at startup for the current user.

Comment: In that case, the place where my app will be used will have only user logged in. Can something be done then?

Comment: I changed the registry to be set in HKCU but with the default UAC settings the application does not start on boot. However, if I turn off the UAC settings, the application does start on boot. This is the same behavior that I get if I set the registry in HKLM exept that I require admin prevliiges to set registry in HKLM. Why is that application not starting up with the default UAC settings and how can this be solved